# Where can I buy an Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I need to buy an Ubuntu phone, where can I buy it? It is unavailable everywhere.

Comment: This isn't "a problem that can't be reproduced." I also don't think we should see it as a shopping recommendation or otherwise off-topic--the key part is "unavailable everywhere." [dobey's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/950026) explains this and it will be valuable to people for years to come. If necessary we could edit this, though I think it's fine as-is. Although I *don't* think SE-wide policy *demands* we keep this open, I think the advice ["Don't hit them over the head with your scope"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) applies.

Comment: @EliahKagan I concur. Voting to reopen

Answer (score 25):

You cannot buy a new retail phone with Ubuntu from anywhere, now. A few months ago, Canonical [announced](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/05/canonical-ends-development-of-its-phone-to-focus-on-cloud-and-iot/) that it is ending development of Unity, and the phone projects.

You may be able to find a used phone on eBay or similar sites, or you may buy certain models of phone, and flash an image from [ubports](https://ubports.com) onto the device. Even if you buy an original Ubuntu phone, you will likely need to flash over to a ubports image, to get updates and use an app store.

Comment: Worth noting that at the end of 2017 the app store will go offline and nothing will work anymore. Used is likly just no worth it now. https://www.networkworld.com/article/3191867/open-source-tools/ubuntu-phone-security-updates-end-in-june-app-store-closing.html

Comment: The ubports image no longer relies on any hosted services from Canonical, I think.

Comment: May we have any other Linux version's phones or not anymore?

Comment: Android is a version of Linux. As for other Linux based systems on phones, I don't know. And anyway, it's off topic, as this site is about Ubuntu.