# Update please: Is there a phone in the U.S. that is supported by Verizon, and can run ubuntu effectively?

Tags: networking, phone

I am restricted to using Verizon as my carrier due to coverage barriers. I would like to get a phone that runs ubuntu well, and is supported by Verizon. There was a lot of talk in 2013 regarding Verizon Wireless joining Ubuntu's Carrier Advisory Group, did anything come of this? Are there any phones supported by Verizon that can be converted to Ubuntu? Hoping for good news!

Comment: There are no phones that can be "converted to Ubuntu" any more.

Comment: I'd think there's no point buying an Ubuntu phone anymore, seeing as the project's been killed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/950023/where-can-i-buy-an-ubuntu-phone